# AS3 - Problems with Functions that Return Values of Variables from Loaded Data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5.5

I am trying to make a blitting engine, and this part is really giving me a hard time. I am trying to make an external class to do all of the xml parsing from the file that texture packer spits out. I made a class in my utilities package called XmlParserBlit.as

I was hoping to be able to just instantiate it and call the one function for it to do it's job, something like this:

```
var _xmlParser:XmlParserBlit = new XmlParserBlit();
_blitDataAry = _xmlParser.getAryFromBlitXmlData("blit_test_4.xml");
```

However, it seems like it's not going to be that easy. The function inside of the XmlParserBlit class has an event listener that triggers a function to happen when the loading is complete. It seems that flash just keeps going on through the function, and the trace("Finished Array: " + _xmlDataAry); just returns a blank array. Is there some way for me to wait for the complete listener to be finished? Or maybe I can back the responsibility on returning a value from getAryFromBlitXmlData over to onXmlLoaded?

I am really stumped, and learning how to beat this problem will open my mind for how to tackle similar problems. Thanks.

```
public function getAryFromBlitXmlData(xmlPath:String):Array
    {
            _xmlDataAry = []

            _xmlPath = xmlPath;

            _testXml = new XML();
            _testXmlRequest = new URLRequest(_xmlPath);
            _testXmlLoader = new URLLoader();

            _testXmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXmlLoaded);
            _testXmlLoader.load(_testXmlRequest);

            trace("Finished Array: " + _xmlDataAry);

            return _xmlDataAry;

    }

    protected function onXmlLoaded(event:Event):void
    {

        _loadedXML = new XML(event.target.data);

        var theSprites:XMLList = _loadedXML..sprite

            for each ( var _rectSprite:XML in theSprites)
            {

                            //--------------------------------------
                            //  do some string manipulations here
                            //--------------------------------------                        
            }

        var _rectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(_xValue, _yValue, _widthValue, _heightValue);

        var miniAry:Array = [_rectangle, _xOffsetValue, _yOffsetValue]

        _xmlDataAry.push(miniAry);


                //* want to return _xmlDataAry to the getAryFromBlitXmlData function

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onXmlLoaded` won't trigger until AFTER the load function finishes asynchronously.
Your best bet would be to make `getAryFromBlitXmlData` not return a value, and handle your `_xmlDataArray` inside of `onXmlLoaded`

Comment: Are you grabbing your XML from over a network? If not, you probably don't want to use events to load your data... I would suggest doing something more like:

`protected function loadXML(filename:String):Array
    {
        _loadedXML = new XML(filename);
        // do things
       return _xmlDataArray;
    }`

Comment: It is meant to be eventually go over a network. It will be in an online game, and the xml is loaded from the respository/webserver. I don't see why that makes a difference though. When you use xml don't you need to wait until the load is complete or you will get errors?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure the XML is loaded before you process it, but in your code, you're not.

Comment: exactly, but how can you tell the function to stop and wait for it to process?

Comment: You don't. In your case, you'll need to make some kind of loop that just doesn't act until  `_xmlDataArray != []`

Comment: ah that will work. I ended up pulling the first part out into the parent class and passing the loaded xml to the XmlParser class